# Using Node.js to process Adobe Acrobat javascript calls

Tags: node.js, acrobat

Is it possible to call the Adobe Acrobat Javascript functionality in a node.js application to convert a PDF to an EPS?

http://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-save-pdf-acrobat-javascript

In the Adobe JavaScript API Reference there is a document object method .saveAs(...) that takes a cConvID paramtere (com.adobe.acrobat.eps) which accept an output path and render eps but I'm unclear as to how I can use this process in an automated fashion to process any PDF file.

Comment: Check this project https://www.npmjs.org/package/acrobat